# Pytest Assert vs Python Assert

Tags: pytest, assert

I am using **pytest asserts** to validate data and data conditions. I wanted to know if this is the same as **Python assert** and is it a good practice to use pytest assert to validate any test condition.

I could not find anywhere - NOT - to use pytest assert.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

From the [pytest docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/assert.html) the assert is just the standard python assert. Other packages may have their own assert methods with custom functionality though.

Note that if you are using python's assert you may need to check the implementation of the `__eq__` method for some objects as the default for some objects is to just check if they point to the same address in memory.

For example, say you have a class `TestClass` where `num` is a string and `id` is an int

```
class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name, id):
        self._name = name
        self._id = id
```

Now if you instantiate two instances of TestClass like so:

```
test1 = TestClass("test", 1)
test2 = TestClass("test", 1)
```

Then `assert test1 = test2` will give False by default as they are two separate objects.

However, you can override the `__eq__` method in a class like this:

```
    class TestClass2:
        def __init__(self, name, id):
            self._name = name
            self._id = id

        def __eq__(self, other_test_class):
            return (self._name = other_test_class._name) and (self._id = other_test_class._id)
```

Now if you define:

```
test1 = TestClass2("test", 1)
test2 = TestClass2("test", 1)
```

Then `assert test1 == test2` gives True.

Some other packages may have their own assert function and set of objects where this functionality is explicitly handled by the assert.

As for which to use that is mostly a matter of preference or who else you are working with. Best practice is to use the same methods your coworkers use. Outside of that, I would prefer base python functions because most should know how to use them, which may not be true for other packages.

Comment: As an extension to the above, can the pytest asserts be disabled, as they can done in python ?  Thank you for the quick update

Comment: Can you give an example for the asserts you are talking about?

Comment: assert (recCount == record[0]), "Items Count Not Successful "       I am using assert in my class methods and those methods are being called from the test.py   
       So my question here is - my test status depends on asserts result and if the assert is disabled, using the options -O and -OO python parameters - my condition will not be executed or will not yield correct result, so how do we handle this.       I was going through the Power of 10 in another question, to disabled asserts selectively

Comment: @mattyx17 I think you mean "assert test1 == test2" in your post - your first use of that statement only has the assignment operator. I tried to edit it, but annoyingly stackoverflow doesn't accept single-character edits.